# What do I do when I decommission a circuit breaker?

Tags: electrical-panel

We are removing some electric heating, and do *not* want to have a box in the wall where the wiring terminates. What is considered safe and appropriate at the box? Remove the breaker and tape over the gap in the panel cover? leave the breaker in place with no wire connected? Some more robust way to fill the hole in the panel cover after removing the breaker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

- Leave the breaker in place with no wires connected.
- Filler plate. If you have a relatively modern panel then they should be easy to find. For example, Home Depot stocks several, [such as this 3-pack for Square D HomeLine](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-HomeLine-Filler-Plates-3-Pack-HOMFPCP/202353318):

[image: filler plates]

Keep in mind that you need to make sure to get the right type for your brand/panel type.

If you have another panel where you can use the breakers (that is often the case with professionals, not nearly as often with DIY) then replacing breakers with filler plates makes sense. Otherwise, while the cost is pretty low for filler plates, there are no advantages that I know of. Plus if you leave the breakers in place then you *might* be able to use them again someday for a new circuit, depending on the type of breaker.

Comment: Left in place and labeled spare. Those fillers always slide around or fall out when you take the cover off.

Answer (score 2):

> Remove the breaker and tape over the gap in the panel cover?

Absolutely not. Panel blank cover plates must be UL-Listed for purpose and application. Your panel labeling may state the approved cover plate model.

> leave the breaker in place with no wire connected? Some more robust way to fill the hole in the panel cover after removing the breaker?

Without a doubt, the most robust blank filler **is a breaker**. It is fine to leave it in place, marked "unused" on the breaker schedule.

(the breaker schedule is either labeling on/near the breaker, or on the cover, or a chart nearby, which states what each breaker powers.  It is mandatory.)

I find that approved blanking plates are extremely flimsy, and expensive, and degrade over time.

Since current will not move through the breaker, *alien breakers* should be OK as a blanking device if they physically fit properly.  (Alien breakers are one not made or approved for the panel, e.g. a Square D breaker in a Murray panel).  So if you are de-lousing the panel of aliens, feel free to use them for blanks if they fit.